# How do you add an app icon to the home screen (without long press)?

Tags: applications, screen

I used to be able to search for an app, long press it, then drag it to the home screen.

Now, long press doesn't seem to exist anymore.  Searching for that online says that you don't need long press anymore and that there are other ways of doing things.

How do you add an app to your home screen without long press existing anymore?

For now, the best I can do is to add a widget for the app, then press the widget, but that's an absurd solution.

Edit: System is updated to S3RQS32.20-42.10-12-5-4 on Nov. 4, 2023
Android version 12 on a Motorola Moto G Power.

Edit: I don't know what the expected behavior is.  Is it the case that long press should work to add an app to the home screen in Android 12 (like it did in previous versions)?  The fact that people are confused by this question suggests that it should work and the problem should be that long press isn't working.  Or was the method changed in an update and I just don't know the new one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated with OEM and version info.  I need more information in order to ask the right question.  Can we start with basics?  How do you add an app to the home screen?  Why doesn't long press register as anything other than a tap anymore?

Comment: So when you see the list of apps, you are you not able to press and hold on the desired app and drag (without lifting finger) upward and the home screen doesn't appear where you can then place the icon?

Comment: Correct.  That used to be how I would do it, and that's not happening anymore.

Caveats: List of apps is either from the search (swipe up from the middle of the screen) or from settings > apps > all apps.  Neither or which will allow me to press and hold and then drag.  Instead, it registers as a tap (getting the app info from settings) or nothing (from search).

Comment: First, from settings, identify your launcher app and clear it's cache and reboot. If that doesn't help try a different launcher, say, Nova and see if it is the same behavior. If it is the same on both launchers the problem maybe with your system

Comment: I don't have a launcher other than the default.

Comment: That's fine. Did you clear cache and reboot?.Also see in settings, probably under accessibility if "touch and hold" is set to"short" (on my Pixel I see this, can't say about your device)

Comment: The "problem" is that manufacturer can customize their Android OS and thus change the behavior. OTOH, have you tried long-pressing and then moving the finger somewhere else while holding the app? I have Pixel 3a on Android 12 and after long-pressing the app from the launcher, after it shows the app shortcut, I (just) need to move my finger while holding it, then the home screen will be shown.